# Позиционирование текста на фоне

Tags: html, css, css3

Макет: https://codepen.io/maxtor/pen/prwyvZ

```css
.about-smartprogress {   
  background-image: url(http://ico.smartprogress.do/img/index/bg-about-smartprogress.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 1000px;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}

.grant {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 580px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.2rem;
}

.top {
  padding-bottom: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-smartprogress">
  <div class="grant">
    <div class="top">
      В 2015 году мы получили<br/>
      грант Startup Chile
    </div>
    <div class="botom">
      От правительства Чили
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Возможно ли спозиционировать текст в div.grant таким образом, чтобы он был всегда привязан к определенному месту на фоновой картинки (нужно чтобы текст в блоке располагался выше и ниже числа 35.000, как на фоне)?
Сейчас при изменении размера экрана, текст сдвигается и наползает на число.

Comment: Навскидку: может быть поможет задание контейнеру фона имитирование пропорции фона через вертикальный педдинг псевдоэлемента(загуглите как сделать адаптивный квадрат на css). А затем делать отступы дочерних текстовых блоков исходя из рамеров этого адаптивного контейнера. Первое, что приходит в голову.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если можно картинку из бэкграунда переместить в разметку, то можно так:

```css
.about-smartprogress { 
 position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.about-smartprogress img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.grant {
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 57%;
  left: calc(50% - 150px);
  height: 19%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.2rem;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-smartprogress">
  <img src="http://ico.smartprogress.do/img/index/bg-about-smartprogress.jpg">
  <div class="grant">
    <div class="top">
      В 2015 году мы получили<br/>
      грант Startup Chile
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      От правительства Чили
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Единственное подобрать размеры шрифтов для разной ширины экрана, отступ слева и ширину соответственно  блока grant ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="about-smartprogress">
    <p class="top">
      В 2015 году мы получили<br/>
      грант Startup Chile
    </p>
    <p class="bottom">
      От правительства Чили
    </p>
</div> 

* {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    html,
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .about-smartprogress {
      background-image: url(http://ico.smartprogress.do/img/index/bg-about-smartprogress.jpg);
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      background-position: top;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      height: 800px;
      color: #fff;
      padding-top: 50px;
      padding-bottom: 35px;
      position: relative;
    }

    .top {
      position: absolute;
      top: 57%;
      left: calc(50% - 125px);
      width: 250px;
      height: auto;
      background-color: red;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 1.3rem;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .bottom {
      position: absolute;
      left: calc(50% - 125px);
      bottom: 22%;
      width: 250px;
      height: auto;
      background-color: red;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 1.3rem;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
```

Comment: background-size: 100% 100%;  - Тогда фон начинает искажаться. Требуется именно "cover"